# @click.outside doesn't work on template element in alpine.js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I want to hide and unhide element but instead of just hide it with `display:none`, I want it to be completely removed from the dom. so I use x-if on the template element. but it doesn't work

`<template x-if="open" @click.outside="open=false"> my element </template>`

When I changed above code to use `x-show`, it does work.

`<div x-show="open" @click.outside="open=false"> my element </div>`

but I can't use it (the x-show one), my test will fail if I do so since the `x-show` only add `display:none` not completely removed the element